# Sum evens between 0 and N

Tags: code-golf, number, arithmetic

### Challenge

Given an integer `n`, calculate the sum of **all even numbers** between 0 and `n`

### Examples

```
n     output
-------------
100   2550
255   16256
1000  2502500
```

---

Shortest code in bytes wins

Comment: What are the expected inputs and outputs? What's the winning criterion? Please put them in your question instead of in the tags. Also, I'm fairly sure this is a dupe.

Comment: I closed as a dupe of summing odds. I don't think evens and lack of a lower bound changes much. Be aware that that question was poorly received, likely for being too easy. In the future, I'd suggest running challenge ideas through the sandbox on meta.

Comment: @xnor Fair enough. Though this allows for something much simpler like `(n/=2)*n+n`.

Answer (score 0):

### Scala - 18 bytes

shortest I could figure:

```
(0 to i by 2).sum
```

Using an anonymous function:

```
val i = (N:Int) => (0 to N by 2).sum
```

Comment: Your first snippet is neither a function nor a program, you can't assume that a predefined variable exists.